# Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, windows-subsystem-for-linux, nvidia-graphics-card

I tried to check my nvidia driver version within ubuntu 22.04 installed on the WSL2 subsystem installed on Windows 11,however, i got the error "Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system".
My goal is to be able to passthru my RTX 2080 ti (or the GTX 1060) to a guest OS like FreeBSD. Can this be accomplished ? Hope to get support from you on this issue.

On Windows 11 host os it works :

```
# nvidia-smi

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 536.40                 Driver Version: 536.40       CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB  WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 57%   41C    P2              25W / 120W |    710MiB /  3072MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti   WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 31%   40C    P8              21W / 250W |     74MiB / 11264MiB |      0%              |
+_________________________________________+______________________+______________________|
```

on Ubuntu 22.04 guest os it doesn't :

```
# nvidia-smi

Failed to initialize NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
Failed to properly shut down NVML: GPU access blocked by the operating system
```

BUT :

```
# nvcc -V

nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Jun_13_19:16:58_PDT_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.2, V12.2.91
Build cuda_12.2.r12.2/compiler.32965470_0


# python3 --version
Python 3.10.7
```

Within ubuntu 22.04 I have installed cuda-12.2 using the instructions below :

```
# wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/wsl-ubuntu/x86_64/cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin

# sudo mv cuda-wsl-ubuntu.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600

# wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.2.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-12-2-local_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb

# sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-12-2-local_12.2.0-1_amd64.deb

# sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-wsl-ubuntu-12-2-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/

# sudo apt-get update

# sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

Instructions taken from here :

https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=WSL-Ubuntu&target_version=2.0&target_type=deb_network

My PC has 2 graphic cards :

```
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti
```

Below you can see the nvidia driver version installed on WIndows 11 for both the GPUs :

[image: 1]

I have also added the line below to `/home/marietto/.bashrc and to /root/.bashrc` :

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-12.2/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

and I did :

```
# source /home/marietto/.bashrc
# source /root/.bashrc
```

After having rebooted,I don't know what else do.

**Some background :**

Windows Version = Windows 11 PRO Version 10.0.22000.2176

WSL Version = 1.3.11.0

I'm using WSL 2

Kernel Version = 6.1.38-microsoft-standard

Distro Version = Ubuntu 22.10

Version kernel: 5.15.90.2-3

Version WSLg: 1.0.54

Version MSRDC: 1.2.4240

Version Direct3D: 1.608.2-61064218

Version DXCore: 10.0.25880.1000-230602-1350.main

Comment: Why are you using 1.3.11.0 instead of 1.2.5? What version of WSLg are you using. How is your kernel version 6.1.38 when the latest as of 2 days ago is only 5.15.90.3?

Comment: 1.3.11.0 is the version that I've got when I've upgraded WSL2. So :
Version kernel: 5.15.90.2-3
Version WSLg: 1.0.54
Version MSRDC: 1.2.4240
Version Direct3D: 1.608.2-61064218
Version DXCore: 10.0.25880.1000-230602-1350.main
Version Windows: 10.0.22000.2176

Comment: Kernel Version = 6.1.38-microsoft-standard is because I have recompiled the kernel because I need to have the ZFS support for one of my disks and I've chosen to recompile zfs to make it work on that kernel. Should I use another kernel ? which one ?

Comment: My suggestion get CUDA working with the current version of the Linux kernel instead of introducing a unknown variable

Comment: Some days ago I tried with kernel 5.15.38,but ZFS didn't compile,so I chosen 6.1.38. Please give a look at this post : https://www.reddit.com/r/openzfs/comments/14v2vv7/make1_no_rule_to_make_target_modulemodulesymvers/

Comment: very thanks man. You fixed the problem. I'm using kernel 5.15.90.3 and nvidia-smi is working here.